# What is this group?

Tags: word, knowledge

The chameleon and sphinx are examples of this. So are the birds and the bee's larder, if you are generous

A clue: The sphinx has the fewest scales, and the bee's larder has the most

Another clue: The chameleon and bird aren't quite the same as the sphinx and bee's larder

Comment: For clarification, do you mean the larder of the birds and the bees?

Comment: @hexomino No, the larder refers just to the bee's larder

Comment: I would recommend that instead of just writing "That isn't correct" under each incorrect answer, you provide a steer - let people know if they are at all partially correct or thinking along the right lines, or even give a clue to help narrow down to the true answer. Otherwise this just becomes a guessing game that will start to accumulate downvotes as a result... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Chameleon, sphinx, nest, and hive are all names of PYTHON (the programming language) tools and collaboration software. But that doesn't use wordplay so I am hoping this is wrong.

Comment: That isn't correct

Answer (score 1):

They are all ...

> ... **moths**.

In particular:

> [*Chameleon moths*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/chameleon-moth);
>  [*Sphingidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingidae), the **sphinx** or
>  **hawk moths**;
>  [*Noctuidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noctuidae), the **owlet moths**;
>  [*Korscheltellus lupulina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_swift_moth), the **common swift**;
>  [*Galleria mellonella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galleria_mellonella), the **honeycomb** moth.

Doubts about the answer:

> There doesn't really seem to be a moth officially called "chameleon moth"; at best that is a vernacular name for different generafor moths or moth caterpillars that can adapt to their surroundings. (Web searches for "chameleon moth" bring up forum discussions about whether moths or caterpillars are suitable food for chameleons.)
>
>  With the exception of the common swift, all species above are called something *moths*, so you can't really say "hoenycomb is an example of a moth". And I'm not sure why we have to be generous.
>
>  But the hint provides some reassurance: Moths (and butterflies) have scales on their wings.

Comment: rot13(Vg'f cbffvoyr gung gur nafjre vf whfg gung gurl nyy unir fpnyrf, fb gur "oveqf naq gur orrf' yneqre" znl unir gb trg n ovg trarebhf.)

Comment: That isn't correct, but it is a group of animals (sort of)

Comment: [Something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chameleon_goby) [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_blenny) [ichthyic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrotfish) [perhaps](https://www.whatsthatfish.com/fish/honeycomb-toby/843)?

Comment: @MOehm Not fish, but you're closer

Comment: Some contradictory clues, possibly spiders.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

> Camouflage?

Because:

> Chameleons can camouflage with their surroundings, and a sphinx is the same color as the sand around it. A bird can blend in with the flowers around it, and a bee can do the same in its larder.

Comment: That isn't correct

Comment: Aww dang ;-; :(

Answer (score 0):

Possibility that:

> They are numbers.

> CHAMEL**EON** (one anagrammed), **S**PH**I**N**X** (six) Bird as in, PIG**EON** (one anagrammed) Bee's larder as in, H**ONE**Y (one)

Comment: That isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> Chameleon, Sphinx, The Byrds and The Honeycombs are the names of rock bands.

Comment: [These guys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hives) are probably better known than the one you state here... Maybe add some Wikipedia links to add more strength to your answer?

Comment: That isn't correct

Comment: @Stiv, you're right, but the principle of the solution is the same. Incorrect anyway.

Comment: @IchthysKing Stop saying something like "That isn't correct" and start actually helping people get to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Reptile

Explanation:

> Chameleons are obvious. Birds evolved from reptiles, and so are considered reptiles cladistically. The sphinx is a shape known as a rep-tile, which is a shape that can be split into smaller-scale versions of itself. A hexagon, the rough shape of a honeycomb cell, is also a rep-tile, but it requires an infinite number of different scales for the split version

Comment: I wonder if the 'wordplay' tag might have helped people in the right direction with their answers